# Pygame installation on Windows - error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, installation, pygame

I have a Win7 64 bit dev machine. I've downloaded and installed Python 2.6.6 32bit. I've also downloaded pygame 1.9.1 for python 2.6 and tried to install it. I got:

```
C:\pygame-1.9.1release>setup.py install
....
running build_ext
building 'pygame._numericsurfarray' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

What should I do?
(I don't have any compiler or visual studio or anything installed, if it's relevant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [PyGame's download page](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) - use the msi file which is a dedicated Windows installation instead of downloading the source and executing:

```
setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a package (Traits) a couple of weeks ago - for me it was because the package was trying to compile extensions and I didn't have Visual Studio.  What worked for me was to install [MinGW](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/) and direct Python to use it as the compiler in the distutils.cfg config file under \Lib\distutils in your Python installation folder.  Looks like [this page](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries) can automate the whole process for you; if you'd prefer to do it manually here's the contents of my distutils.cfg:

[build]

compiler=mingw32

Rerun setup.py and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give an answer that isn't outdated.

**Why does it happen?**

`pygame` is written in C, so it needs to be compiled before it can be installed. `setup.py` tries to compiled it using Visual Studio Build Tools, and if they're not installed on your PC, it fails.

**How do I install pygame?**

Pip provides pre-compiled versions of `pygame` so you don't have to compile them yourself. If you get the error, then it hasn't been compiled for your version of Python yet. Try downgrading Python.

E.g. I had to downgrade from 3.11 to 3.10.

More info: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/